# How to use field variable (a term) from node in field.html.twig for page title

Tags: theming

When viewing a node I want to display an associated vocab term field inline with the node. The vocab is called "field_related". If I add {{ node.field_related.entity.label }} to node.html.twig and view the node it outputs the term, but if I add the same print tag to my custom twig template field--node--title--topic.html.twig ("topic" is the content type name) it doesn't output anything.
What do I need to do to get it so I can print node.field_related.entity.label in field--node--title--topic.html.twig?

I've been trying various combinations of how to write the tag and fiddling with theme_preprocess_field but so far all I've gotten is a headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a field template the parent entity of the field is stored in `element['#object']`, so you can access the taxonomy field of the node like this:

```
{{ element['#object'].field_related.entity.label }}
```