# How to check in Twig file whether node has a field?

Tags: 8, theming

In my twig file i try to override the field. In the {% if %} clause I need to check whether a field has particular value, if yes then assign the value as a class.

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if node.language.value == "English"  %}
    {% set example_classes = 'english' %}
   {% else %}
    {% set example_classes = node.language.value %}
  {% endif %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass('field', field_name, example_classes) }}>
    {{ item.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

the line {% if node.language.value == "English"  %} brings nothing, how can I get the value of the node's field_language in twig file?

In the field.html.twig a list of available variables is specified:

```
Available variables:
* - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
* - label_hidden: Whether to show the field label or not.
* - title_attributes: HTML attributes for the title.
* - label: The label for the field.
* - multiple: TRUE if a field can contain multiple items.
* - items: List of all the field items. Each item contains:
*   - attributes: List of HTML attributes for each item.
*   - content: The field item's content.
* - entity_type: The entity type to which the field belongs.
* - field_name: The name of the field.
* - field_type: The type of the field.
* - label_display: The display settings for the label.
```

Comment: Are you really looking for a custom field `field_language`, or the language of the node itself? - If the latter, `{{ node.langcode.value }}` could help you further.

Comment: no, I need a custom field.

Comment: Then it's usually an array (field item list). For a single value field with index `0`. E.g., `{{ node.field_language[0].value }}` - PS.: `{{ dump(node.field_language) }}` is a useful tool to explore a field's data structure.

Comment: The twig code seems to be OK, only that field names of custom fields normally start with `field_`, so `{{ node.field_language.value|clean_class }}` should display the field value. I've added a filter to get valid class names without the need to run them through if conditions.

Comment: I have edited my question, in the notation there is a list of available variables. Can I extend it, so that I am able to reach other custom fields of the node?

Comment: In a field template the parent node is in a different place `{{ element['#object'].field_language.value }}`, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260313/how-to-use-field-variable-a-term-from-node-in-field-html-twig-for-page-title

Answer (score 0):

I'm a friend of template pre-processing, in order to keep presentation logic separated from (advanced) field processing.

Therefore, I suggest a [hook_preprocess_HOOK()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.6.x) implementation in your theme's `*.theme` file and outline this approach:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for nodes.
 */
mytheme_preprocess_node(array &$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $example_class = '';
  if (
    $node->hasField('field_language')
    && !$node->field_language->isEmpty()
  ) {
    $variables['example_class'] = strtolower($node->field_language->value);
  }
  $variables['example_class'] = $example_class;
}
```

So you could access the newly added template variable `{{ example_class }}` within your node template:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {%
    set field_classes = [
      'field',
      field_name,
      example_class,
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(field_classes) }}>
    {{ item.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

If you'd like to stick to just altering your template, you can also access all fields of a `node` entity within its templates by using the `{{ node }}` variable.

Keep in mind, that unrendered/preprocessed fields of the original entity usually are [FieldItemLists](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemListInterface.php/interface/FieldItemListInterface/8.6.x). So you'll access an array of field item instances keyed by their delta:

```
{% if node.field_language and node.field_language[0].value == 'English' %}
...
{% endif %}
```

The `{{ dump() }}` Twig function can help you to debug [your available values](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates).

Comment: You can consider class names part of the presentation logic. The core classy theme for example has no preprocess hooks, it has not even a classy.theme file.