# Accessing a FieldItemList value within Twig

Tags: 8, theming

I've tried several different ways to try access the value of a field item list value without success.

The item in question within Drupal 8 is a float text field and I need the unmodified number from this. The value gained from the standard `content.field_latitude[0]['#markup']` call is rounded in some manner so I want to grab the one located in the `#items` object as shown in the screen shot below.

I can get this via a preprocessor in the theme file but want to avoid using a preprocess if I can and want to gain access directly in the twig file.

[image]

Comment: See my answer to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/269957/57012 - you could use the `{{ node }}` object instead of the preprocessed `{{ content }}` variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the value you've highlighted in the debug output in Twig:

```
{{ content.field_latitude['#items'].0.value }}
```

You can see this follows the path you've shown in the screenshot, but missing the protected values array. Instead it uses `.value` on the field item, which calls a magic method `__get('value')` to retrieve the protected property.

But as @MarioSteinitz [commented](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269965/accessing-a-fielditemlist-value-within-twig#comment331760_269965) it's better to use the `node` object:

```
{{ node.field_latitude.value }}
```

Because `content` is not an API like the methods of the node object. It is a render array which can change when you configure the field display differently or install a layout module.

And never use the `|raw` filter on user input!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `raw` filter:

```
{{ content.field_latitude[0]|raw }}
```